# Use powershell drive to remove git branch

Tags: powershell

I would like to manipulate git branches using the notation of a powershell drive.

For example for environment variables we can do:

```
ls env:
```

to list all variables, or

```
rm env:JRE_PATH
```

to delete environment variable `JRE_PATH`.

Could I do the same thing with git branches? Essentially I would like to have a `br:` drive such that I can say

```
ls br:
```

or

```
rm br:test_branch
```

Comment: I don't think that's feasible. The PSProvider for this would have to gather all branches of all local (and remote?) repositories in the single namespace `br`. How would you handle multiple branches with the same name (master specifically)? Even if you used distinct namespaces per repository, how would the provider know the location of the repositories without traversing all filesystems?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers in my simple case I would be happy to make it work for local branches only.